# Powershell command for Create OSDisk and DataDisk snapshot

Tags: powershell, snapshot

I am writing powershell script for capture OS-disk snapshot for Azure VM but While configuring snapshot I am getting some error. 
I am using below command to create snapshot.I am using managed disk.

```
New-AzSnapshotConfig -OsType Linux -CreateOption copy -SourceUri Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.OSDisk -DiskSizeGB 40 -Location 'East US'
```

Not sure how to do that. If anyone could you please help me to solve this issue.

**OUTPUT**

```
WARNING: Breaking changes in the cmdlet 'New-AzSnapshotConfig' :
WARNING:  - "The output type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.Models.PSSnapshot' is changing"
 - The following properties in the output type are being deprecated :
 'EncryptionSettings'
- The following properties are being added to the output type :
 'EncryptionSettingsCollection' 'HyperVGeneration'


WARNING: NOTE : Go to https://aka.ms/azps-changewarnings for steps to suppress this breaking change warning, and other information on breaking changes in 
Azure PowerShell.


ResourceGroupName            : 
ManagedBy                    : 
Sku                          : 
TimeCreated                  : 
OsType                       : Linux
HyperVGeneration             : 
CreationData                 : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.CreationData
DiskSizeGB                   : 40
EncryptionSettingsCollection : 
ProvisioningState            : 
Id                           : 
Name                         : 
Type                         : 
Location                     : East US
Tags                         : 
EncryptionSettings           : 

Thanks
Rohit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you go to the link provided in the warning note? It [says very clearly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/documentation/breaking-changes/breaking-changes-messages-help.md#how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-warnings):

> How do I get rid of the warnings?
>
> To suppress these warning messages, set the environment variable 'SuppressAzurePowerShellBreakingChangeWarnings' to 'true'.
>
> Set-Item Env:\SuppressAzurePowerShellBreakingChangeWarnings "true"

The error message is trying to tell you that the property `EncryptionSettings` you see in the output you provided will soon be changing from a single property of some type, to a collection property that you would have to iterate over to find all of the settings. They are trying to let you know that if you are capturing the output of `New-AzSnapshotConfig` to a variable and then calling `$variable.EncryptionSettings`, your code will work for now, but in the next breaking change release, that call will stop working. Most likely, since that property will no longer exist, the result of that call will simply be a `$NULL`.

So suppress this warning at your own risk because Microsoft is trying to do you a service here and let you know that if you don't do something about this your code could break. But if you are certain that you never reference property then you have nothing to worry about.